# c# reflection to call dynamic method

Tags: c#, reflection

I have seen various examples of reflection to dynamically call methods by sending a string.  Most of the examples show how to very easily dynamically set the class, method and parameters.  My requirement is slightly different and can't get it to work.  The following line is what I would include hardcoded.

```
Mailer.CallBack(parameters).Send();
```

`Mailer` is the class, `Callback` is the method, `parameters` is parameters, but how on earth do I ensure it calls it dynamically with the `.send()` appended?

The answer escapes me so hope someone can help.

Steve.

Comment: "It calls it dynamically with the `.Send()` appended?" - what does this mean? Can you show an example of code you want to *write* that you expect to behave the same as your "hardcoded" example?

Comment: That's basically two method calls: 1. `Callback` 2. `Send` on the return value of `Callback`

Comment: millimoose, answered below but just to be clear I intended to use reflection to call the above hardcoded value albeit with the ability to change the class/method/parameters based on data being passed to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All it means when you chain methods like that is that you're calling the second method on the result of the first method.  In other words

```
Mailer.CallBack(parameters).Send();
```

should be exactly equivalent to

```
var callbackResult = Mailer.CallBack(parameters);
callbackResult.Send();
```

so you should be able to do the equivalent of the first line using reflection, and then just make the second call normally.

(To put it another way, when you make the call to `CallBack`, it has no awareness of the `.Send()` that is appended to it. `CallBack` does its thing, and then returns, and then `.Send()` is called on the result.)

Comment: Thanks Jacob, Totally makes sense to me, it never occured to me to break it into chunks.  Shame it took all weekend not to work that out :-(  You were very quick off the mark, so I can't mark it as answered yet, but will do shortly.